# Claims Authentication ASP.NET vNext

Tags: asp.net-core

When adding a claim to the user, the claims information does not get recorded as a cookie on the page and the information gets lost for all other requests. Why does this happen?

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                var authReq = new AuthenticationViewModel() { password = model.Password, username = model.UserName };
                var userInfo = await _dataService.AuthenticateAsync(authReq);


                var claims = new List<Claim>();
                claims.Add(new Claim("username", userInfo.user.userName));
                claims.Add(new Claim("AddtionalData", userInfo.AddtionalData));

                var user = ClaimsPrincipal.Current;

                var identity = user.Identities.Where(x => x.AuthenticationType == "Custom").FirstOrDefault();

                if (identity == null)
                    identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims.ToArray(), "Custom");

                user.AddIdentity(identity);


                return RedirectToAction("Users", "Index");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
            }

        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Are you using the cookie middleware to sign in the user ? In that scenario you should be doing context.Response.SignIn(identity). In addition are using ASP.NET Identity for creating/storing user information ?

Comment: Where do you check if the password is valid? From which type is `_dataService` variable?

Comment: In my case data service is an interface that calls and API that do all the validation for me. The data that that return gets store as claims. Sorry for typos doing it from my phone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue, I needed to add the following code:

```
context.Response.SignIn(new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim("name", "bob") }, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType));
```

also, I changed the AuthenticationType to be CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType.

Please see link with [Sample](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/c733aa880478ba45029a4686b62d174bade3ab23/samples/CookieSample/Startup.cs)